# Case when statement with IN clause in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark programming and have a scenario to assign a value when a set of values appear in my input. Below is a tradition SQL code I would use to accomplish my task. Need to do the same in Spark.

Sql Code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c.Number IN ( '1121231', '31242323' ) THEN 1 
ELSE 2 END AS Test
FROM   Input  c
```

I am aware of using `when` in spark with just one condition.

```
Input.select(when(Input.Number==1121231,1).otherwise(2).alias("Test")).show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with Spark DataFrames, not RDDs. One thing to note is that you can run SQL queries directly on a DataFrame:

```py
# register the DataFrame so we can refer to it in queries
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "df")

# put your SQL query in a string
query = """SELECT CASE WHEN 
    df.number IN ('1121231', '31242323') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS test 
    FROM df"""

result = sqlContext.sql(query)
result.show()
```

You can also use `select` by creating a [user-defined function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) that mimics your query's case statement:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

# need to pass inner function through udf() so it can operate on Columns
# also need to specify return type
column_in_list = udf(
    lambda column: 1 if column in ['1121231', '31242323'] else 2, 
    IntegerType()
)

# call function on column, name resulting column "transformed"
result = df.select(column_in_list(df.number).alias("transformed"))
result.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked. Is there a way we can use the when function directly on the spark dataframe and give a list of values?

Comment: I think I found what I wanted to do.
df.when(df.char.isin('H','O','M'),1).otherwise(0)

Comment: @user3258274 That works too. You can also extract the list of values from the column by converting the DataFrame into an rdd and collecting, like this: `rdd = df.rdd; rdd.map(lambda x: x.transform).collect()`.